# (Android studio) Error after upgrade 4.1.2 > 4.2.0

Tags: java, android, jwt

When android version was 4.1.2, this code worked well.
But after 4.2.0, code doesn't work
This is my code below

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            String accessKey = ("code erased");//api key 1
            String secretKey = ("code erased");//api key 2
            String serverUrl = ("https://api.upbit.com");

            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretKey);
            String jwtToken = JWT.create()
                    .withClaim("access_key", accessKey)
                    .withClaim("nonce", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .sign(algorithm);

            String authenticationToken = "Bearer " + jwtToken;
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(serverUrl + "/v1/accounts");
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.addHeader("Authorization", authenticationToken);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"));

            double balance_total = 0.0;
            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray) jsonParser.parse(EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject object = (JsonObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                Double balances = object.get("balance").getAsDouble();
                balance_total += balances;
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And my dependencies are

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    compileOnly 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.auth0.android:jwtdecode:2.0.0'
    api 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-orgjson:0.11.2') { exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'}
    runtimeOnly 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.60'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.15.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    androidTestImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.26.3"
```

I'm using commons-codes 1.10v as a jar file instead of implementation because I use two apis and other api doesn't work with commons-codec implementation.(And it occurs duplicate class if i use jar file and dependencies both)

The error occurs like this

```
W/pclass.apitest: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;-><clinit>()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->EMPTY_STACK_TRACE:[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTATION_PERMISSION:Ljava/lang/RuntimePermission; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->lock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/pclass.apitest: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->daemon:Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->threadLocals:Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->inheritableThreadLocals:Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/pclass.apitest: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
.
.
.
```

Lots of "Accessing hidden field or method" error occurs

Is there any problem with android update
or did I wrong something?

Comment: Did you find out this? My code works, but I see tons of errors in the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing a network request on the Main thread which is a blocking process and android doesn't allow to execute network requests on the Main thread, you should execute it on background thread which won't block UI processing.

Comment: thread exception has been fixed but Accessing is still denied

Comment: Please post the current error, what you are getting now.